# Bug in Scapy - ignoring static ip neighbour (ARP/NDP) entry

Tags: python, linux, networking, ipv6, scapy

I'm trying to send IPv6 packet to subnet where IPv6 NDP(ARP counterpart) is disabled on destination host:

1. Statically specify the ipv6 neighbor (destination host):

```
2007::1 dev enp0s8 lladdr 08:00:27:a1:cd:f0 PERMANENT
```

2. Run the script:

```
#!/bin/python3

from scapy.all import *
from scapy.contrib.gtp import *

ipv6 = IPv6(src="2007::2",dst="2007::1")
udp = UDP(sport=2152, dport=2152)

while True:
    sendp(Ether()/ipv6/udp/"Hello World!")
```

**Expected Result:**
Hello-world packet is sent with specific dst MAC-address (`08:00:27:a1:cd:f0`) according to static ip neighbour entry.

**Actual result:**
“Who has” NDP-packets are sent. After having no answer - broadcast dst MAC-address (`ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`) is set in Hello-world packet. When sending ping packets who has are not sent.

Seem that there is a **bug in [Scapy](https://github.com/secdev/scapy)**.

Comment: IPv6 does not have broadcast. That was eliminated in IPv6 as a bad IPv4 design. Also, `fec1::1` is a bad IPv6 address, using the deprecated site-local addressing that was eliminated with ULA.

Comment: Had the same problem. A work-around was to set dst MAC explicitly with `Ether(dst="08:00:27:a1:cd:f0")`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Scapy doesn't read the NDP cache from the OS. You can specify MAC within Scapy with:

```
conf.netcache.in6_neighbor['2007::1'] = '08:00:27:a1:cd:f0'
```

or with

```
eth = Ether(dst="08:00:27:a1:cd:f0")
```